# How many trucks came empty but bought something

Tags: arrays, database, excel, excel-formula, vba

I think this is the hardest to date I have had to crack - so hard I had a hard time finding a good headline.

So we have a site where trucks come and buy say Gravel, or sand or other building materials.

Sometimes they also unload demolition waste first.

I need to find out a couple of things

1. how many trucks (and from what companys) came empty
2. if they came empty what did they buy from us.
3. what companys are sending full trucks and what are sending empty trucks.
4. a tope 10 of materials they will drive to us from to buy even when coming empty to our facility.
5. a list of all the order numbers that they drove to us til fill and came with empty trucks. ( I have distances linked to order numbers, so now I can estimate the value of our products)

The data I have available:
I have a full data set of when what customer buys what and / or pay to deliver.
E.G.:

[image: Example of how data looks]

I can see the parts I need to split the data into I think it should be something like this

1. find all unique licence plates
2. somehow map if they bought materials within 30 minutes of
   offloading demolition waste (most trucks will come between 2 and 10
   times per day)
3. Present all this data (on a normal day we have about 800 trucks = 2000 lines since they weigh in, weigh out, and then some buy something = 2 more weigh lines)

I can easily find unique licence plates per day (either by formula or by Excel function Data/delete doublets, 
but after that I have no clue where to start.

I think I need some sheets in between, where I somehow mark if a material was bought from an "empty truck" and I need a counter for that .. somehow...

Any help on how to get started is appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate jokes probably more than most on this site, but SO is intended to help people including future people. Perhaps put a title that might be more helpful for people searching for a similar issue?

Comment: For your second requirement can you create a helper column that returns `true` or `false` for the condition you need?

Comment: I suggest tidy up the grammar/question and make it absolutely clear when you want to know about trucks arriving empty v full etc. At the moment, some of the items seems a little ambiguous, or at least not immediately clear. Also, what have you tried? I would limit this to one problem per question so perhaps edit the question to your first problem and use that as a template for the additional items in future questions

Comment: When you say trucks arrive empty - are you showing the unladen weight or just the weight at the time they arrived?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the best way to start is with a helper column (in the following exampes, I have chosen "Column M") to flag whether the truck arrived empty.

In the helper column, you can use something similar to the following formula.

```
{=IF(ISBLANK(B2),0,IF(C2="In",0,IF(B2=$B$2:$B$13,IF($C$2:$C$13="In",IF($A$2:$A$13>(A2-TIME(0,30,0)),0,1),1),1)))}
```

This is an array formula, which means you have to press `ctrl+shift+enter` after pasting it in the cell. Then you can copy that cell down the column.

Just to explain, the first if statement knows the truck is not arriving empty if Column C is 'In'. The second if statement creates an array and tests to see if other the same truck appears in other rows. The third if statement checks to see if the same truck checked 'In' in the matching rows, and the fourth if statement verifies if the time they checked in was less than thirty minutes ago. You can adjust the length by editing the `TIME(0,30,0)` function. The format is `TIME(hours,minuites,seconds)`. Unless the truck matches all three of the second, third and fourth if statements, it is marked as coming empty.

Once you have this helper column, just about all of your tasks are quite simple.

1a: How many trucks came empty? Sum Column M

1b: How many trucks from what company? Create a unique list of companies. Then create a `COUNTIFS` formula based on Column M = 1 and Column K = Company. For example, if `C32` had `Company B` then the formula `=COUNTIFS($M$2:$M$13,1,$K$2:$K$13,C32)` would return `2`

1c: How many times did a truck come empty? Similar to 1b, create a unique list of License Plates, then use a `COUNTIFS` based on Column M = 1 and Column B = License Plate.

2: Similar to 1b, just use a unique list of products tested against Column F

3: Similar to 1b, just create a second column, next to the first that uses `=COUNTIFS($M$2:$M$13,0,$K$2:$K$13,C53,$C$2:$C$13,"In")` Which tests that Column M reports the truck did not come empty, that matches the company in Column K and that the truck came 'In' so you don't double count the same truck when it goes 'out'

4: Just sort list created by number 2. You can highlight the range, right-click and select "Sort" > "Custom Sort", then select the column you want to sort on and largest to smallest.
[image: Custom Sort]

5: There are a couple of different ways, you could do this. The formula

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($M$2:$M$13=1,$J$2:$J$13,""))}
```

(again, entered as an array formula)
would create a comma separated list of order numbers. An alternative if you want a column of order numbers (but would only work if they are actually numbers), is to paste the formula {`=MAX(IF($M$2:$M$13=1,$J$2:$J$13,))`} in the first row of the column (in my example, its `O2`) and then `{=MAX(IF($M$2:$M$13=1,IF($J$2:$J$13<O2,$J$2:$J$13,)))}` in the row below (change the reference to `O2` if you pasted it in a different spot)(again, note that both of these are array formulas). Then copy and paste the second formula down the column. When order numbers of trucks that came in empty are exhausted, the formula will report `0`.